# How do I fix missing text strings after applying the  "tag not found" bug fix?

Tags: steam, titan-quest

Yesterday, I bought *Titan Quest Gold* via Steam and installed it with the German language files. After starting the *Immortal Throne* add-on, it imported my old characters from an old profile. After that, I faced the generally known "tag not found"-bug and fixed it with an update of the `Text_DE.arc (211KB)`.

But there are still many missing tags which seem only to refer to the new features which were included with the add-on. The [enchantment window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUdw7.jpg), for example, is completely unusable.  I've also tried to repatch the game to English but the add-on content texts were still missing.

I have searched for a solution, but I only found fixes for the general "tag not found" bug. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake of overwriting the `Text_DE.arc` in the IT folder with the one which was downloaded by the patch program. This file does *not* go to the resources folder of Immortal Throne. It must be placed in the resources folder of the normal Titan Quest installation, because TQ cascades its resources. After I placed it in the normal TQ resources folder it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I was checking out Titan Quest related questions in here and noticed there are very few. So in case you still need help check out the [TitanQuest.net](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forum.php) forums. If there is a solution that's probably the #1 place where they will be able to answer it.

PS: There is also a [fan-made bugfix patch](http://www.titanquest.net/tq-forum/forums/65-Bugfix-Fanpatch) which solves various known problem with the last official release (the one you get from Steam). It may or may not solve the language files issues, worth checking out.